# React.js: Communication between two children of the same parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component: `Previewer` which renders two children.

```
class Previewer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AudioPlayer />
      <SubtitleRow />
    );
  }
}
```

When the user clicks on `SubtitleRow`, it should pass variables, e.g. `startTime` and `EndTime`, to `AudioPlayer`, which should play audio.

I've read the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html):

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.
>   Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.

I think they have a relationship (siblings), so, is there any way else to implement their communication?

Global event or variable is not recommended, according to JavaScript the Good Parts or something JavaScript design patterns.

Comment: The page you linked talks about parent-child/child-parent relations (although I don't think the latter is very well explained) - to do sibling relations, you can just do these in combination. Make your parent component hold all the logic/state to co-ordinate the child components, pass necessary data into the children via props, pass events back up to the parent (you can do this by passing a callback as a prop). The upside of doing it this way is that your components only care about themselves and what components they control, so things are pretty nicely decoupled.

Comment: See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#callbacks-as-props for an example of using callbacks as props to communicate with a parent component.

Comment: I am new to reactjs but may be this will help.`<AudioPlayer  onClick={someFunction}/>` and then `someFunction:function(){this.setState({x:"/"})}` and then add ` <SubtitleRow this.state.x/>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the state to pass the variables to the AudioPlayer component. Then in your SubtitleRow component you can call the function this.props.onClick(startTime, endTime)

```
class Previewer extends Component {
 constructor() {
     this.state = { 'startTime': 0, 'endTime' : 0 };
     this.handleClick= this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }

 handleClick(startTime, endTime) {
   this.setState({
     'startTime': startTime,
     'endTime': endTime
   });
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <AudioPlayer startTime="{this.state.startTime}" endTime="{this.state.endTime}"/>
      <SubtitleRow onClick="{this.handleClick}" />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yea but how does he get the start and end from SubtitleRow?

Comment: in the SubtitleRow component, he should call this.props.onClick(startTime, endTime), then it will call the handleClick function in the parent component (Previewer) which will refresh the state, then the audio player will be re-render with the new startTime and endTime